# MVC elmah custom errors not redirecting, different results for different browsers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, exception, elmah, custom-errors

This question seems to be all over stackoverflow, but I can't seem to find the right answer.

I setup ELMAH with MVC3, and ELMAH is logging errors as it should. The client, however, is not being redirected to my custom error page. Also, if you're using firefox/chrome, you will be redirected to the default error view under ~/views/shared/error.cshtml, if you're using IE, you'll get a generic HTTP 500 "Page cannot be displayed".

I can successfully navigate to the custom error page I have setup: ~/home/trouble, and it's specified in the web.config... why isn't it being used? and why would IE not show the default error page when FF and chrome do?

I'm new to MVC... please help, I've spent way too much time on this.

My web.config:

```
  <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Home/Trouble" />
  ......
```

My Global.asax:

```
  public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            // commented this out, cause everything says to for ELMAH
            //filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute(""); 
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            // Home and error page
            routes.MapRoute("trouble", "Home/Trouble", new { controller = "Home", action = "Trouble" });
            routes.MapRoute("home", "Home/Index", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

Comment: I found an answer to one part of my problem: IE was set to "Show Friendly HTTP error messages". I still don't understand why my custom error page (~/home/trouble) is not being used when it's set in the web.config. The site continues to use the default error view unders ~/views/shared/error.cshtml...

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm seeing the same problem where it keeps redirecting to `/views/shared/error.cshtml`